# How to use .map to create Buttons with image

Tags: react-native

*I want to create 4 Button including images. Buttons have default image but if array[0] is not empty, then first button should have different image which is array[0]. Rest of them should default image.*

**I tried this :**

*I set default 4 item in array here :*

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          imgUrls: new Array(4),     
          defaultImage: require('../Images/addcircle.png'),
        };

  }
```

**Here,  I take image from another component. It comes to me as base64**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
      {
            const { img: newImgUrl } = nextProps;
            const { img: imgUrl } = this.props;

            if ((newImgUrl !== imgUrl) && !this.state.imgUrls.includes(newImgUrl)) {
                const { imgUrls } = this.state;
                const imgUrlClone = imgUrls.slice(0);

                for (let i = 0; i < imgUrls.length; i += 1) {
                    if (!imgUrlClone[i]) {                  
                        imgUrlClone[i] = newImgUrl;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                this.setState({ imgUrls: imgUrlClone });

            }
      }

renderContent = () => {

            return imgUrls.map((url, index) => {
                return (
                <View key={index} >                
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.removeImg(index)}>
                    <View style={{ height: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', aspectRatio: 1 }}>
                      <Image
                        source={url !== '' ? { uri: url } : this.state.defaultImage}
                        style={{ height: '90%', width: '90%' }}
                      />                    
                   </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>
                );
            }); 

      };


render() {
   return (
    <View>
  {this.renderContent()}
     </View>
)

}
```

*This isn't work.*

Comment: Can you provide a CodeSandBox or something? Im thinking probaly url is not and empty string but undefined or null and thats why that condition is not caught. did you try just using uri : url || this.state.defaultImage?

Answer (score 0):

Took the liberty to create a VERY simple [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/134wjq0314)
Is this what you were trying to achieve? if so, your issues was probably the condition

**Edited:**

*I want to see this buttons on screen. But these are not shown. These are default image*

[image]

then when I send image, I need to change for example first Image. then second... But when I click button, it adds image which I send  but it seems like this: 
[image]

As i said, it should go first place, then when i send second image, it should go second place. I used code which is below but it doesnt show default images and when click, it comes like I show on top.

I hope i explained clearly, i cant use codesandbox because i call webservise there are so manythings behind.

Comment: If i click button, it adds image which is { uri: url }. If click one more time it adds second image. Screen is empty no default image or sended image. But What i want , there must be 4 default image on screen and when I click button, it will change first button's image. then second ...

Comment: Can you give a CodeSandBox, I dont really understand what you need. or just edit mine to show me an example.